# How to make audio and video streaming servers work?

Tags: server, video, media

I am PHP MySQL developer and I am interested in the way television and radio are broadcasted over Internet live. I want to know how it works and and what are its requirements (which package of which programming language offers the best).

And please clarify me:

Websites are stored in servers. From my desktop, if I want to broadcast some video, then I need to connect to webserver (to upstream the video). Is there an application to do that (or do I have to code that or embed in my web application and which programming language would be suitable (does Python support that))? And I also need a script to handle the upstreamed video or audio (can I do that with PHP)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the internet radios & televisions out there use **HTTP** protocol to stream. A part of the pie for **RTSP** (after **MMS**) and **RTMP**, but it's marginal. Here are the list of the most popular streaming servers:

- [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/download) - the legendary streaming server. Supports only HTTP streaming and is very easy to setup.
- [IceCast](http://www.icecast.org) - this open source project has been developer to cover limitations of SHOUTcast. It is widely used and as recommandable as SHOUTcast. It also supports HTTP streaming.
- [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/server.aspx) - An RTSP based streaming server (before it was MMS). It also supports HTTP streaming, but you need a specific encoder. It is also widely used, but will cost you more in licensing.
- [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com) - RTMP based streaming (Flash) but also supports all possible streaming protocols such as HTTP, RTMPE, RTMPT, RTMPTE, RTMPS, MPEG-TS, etc. Not free, but you get what you paid for! Probably the best choice. It has a very well designed API (it has been programmed in Java) and will let you control and extend most things.

There are other solutions that I know less, so I just list them:

- [Darwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Streaming_Server)
- [Flash Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Media_Server) (also widely used especially in on-demand video)
- [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) (Open Source FMS alternative)
- [Helix](http://www.realnetworks.com/products-services/helix-server-proxy.aspx)

Here is a [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems) of all servers.

I would go for [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/download) or [IceCast](http://www.icecast.org) first, the use [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com) if you are serious about streaming (because of the capabilities and the API).

Comment: now i get the idea that i need a streaming server. i thought i could sit in my desktop and broadcast audio and video connecting to a normal website.

Comment: Https://net7mma.codeplex.com is another example which should be added to that list.

Answer (score 2):

Multimedia streaming is mostly done using a protocol called [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol). And there are a number of commercial and open source implementations that handle this for you.